# Is it possible to prevent merging a green pipeline in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I would like to not allow users to merge a merge request that has a passing pipeline, because that particular pipeline is a different version than the pipeline that makes all tests, security checks, etc.

The passing pipeline is a "fast pipeline" (only builds doesn't test) and is configured by some environment variables in our gitlab instance.

Could I have passing pipelines that cannot be merged? Maybe by adding some conditions on the gitlab-ci.yml?

I read the docs but were not useful as most of the time, the projects have only a pipeline, and they do not contemplate the possibility of triggering multiple types of pipelines.

Comment: Add a failing job at the end ?

Comment: Yes you're right, that I idea crossed my mind @Ôrel but the optic of having a failed job is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bot user to a [required approval](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/#required-approvals) rule (requires Premium subscription) and use a CICD job with the bot user token to [approve MRs via the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html) only after full tests pass.

Might look something like a job in the final stage of your pipeline that has similar `rules:` to your "full" pipeline:

```yaml
stages:
  # ...
  - approve_mr

approval_job:
  stage: approve_mr  # or the builtin ".post" stage can also be used
  rules:
    - # ... same rules as "full" (not "fast") pipeline job(s)
  script:
    - # ... script MR approval via API here
```

You could also use `needs:` or `dependencies:` as another way to ensure the required jobs are successful before this job runs.

[Webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) could also be used as an alternative to the pipeline job -- the hook might receive MR/pipeline events and checks if the full pipeline is configured ran successfully before submitting the approval.

In GitLab ultimate, there is also [external status checks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/status_checks.html) which could also achieve something similar.

---

Without GitLab Premium, you can kind of approximate the behavior of a required approval by using comment threads (similarly, create/resolve [with the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/discussions.html#create-new-merge-request-thread)) and enable the setting to [prevent merge unless all threads are resolved](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/discussions/#prevent-merge-unless-all-threads-are-resolved). However, it's worth noting any user with permissions can resolve a thread, so it's not an impassable barrier, but it should help prevent accidents.

Comment: I suppose least-effort solution is to use a comment yes, thanks for the idea!